# How can I apply MPI on a single function

Tags: c, mpi

I need to run the function `generator` in my code in parallel on two CPUs. The project has two files `main.c` & `cartes.c`, and it's running sequential.

`main.c` file contains a for loop that calls the function `generator`

`main.c`:

```
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
int id;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);
.
.
.
for (iter_sec = 0; iter_sec < long_of_seq; iter_sec++) { //
    uint64_t Xg1 = generator(&K[0], iter_sec, ratio1, ratio2, ratio3, ratio4, m1, m2, id);
    sequence[iter_sec] = Xg1;
    .
    .
}
useTheSequenceArrayResultFromTheForLoopToCaclulateAndPrintTheFinalResult(sequence);
.
.
.
```

The `cartes.c` file contains the `generator` fnction

`cartes.h`

```
uint64_t generator (key *K,int iter_sec,double  ratio1, double  ratio2,double ratio3, double ratio4,uint64_t m1, uint64_t m2, int id);
```

`cartes.c`

```
.
.
.
uint64_t generator(key* K, int iter_sec, double ratio1, double ratio2, double ratio3, double ratio4, uint64_t m1, uint64_t m2, int id){
    K->X_s = someFunction(...);
    K->X_s = someOtherFunction(...);

    Xresult = K->X_p ^ K->X_s;
    return Xresult;
}
.
.
.
```

What I'm trying to do is calculating the result of the function `generator` on two CPUs. I pass the processor's rank id to the function `generator`. If the rank id is `0` I need to call `someFunction`, and if the rank is `1` I need to call `someOtherFunction`. In the end I need to return the XOR`^` of the results from `someFunction` and `someOtherFunction`.

What I tried to do is this:

```
.
.
.
uint64_t generator(key* K, int iter_sec, double ratio1, double ratio2, double ratio3, double ratio4, uint64_t m1, uint64_t m2, int id){
    if (id == 0) {
        K->X_s = someFunction(...);
    }
    else if(id == 1){
        K->X_s = someOtherFunction(...);
    }

    Xresult = K->X_p ^ K->X_s;
    return Xresult;
}
.
.
.
```

But the modified function above doesn't work.

When I try to run the code:

```
mpicc main.c -o saving
mpirun -np 4 ./saving
```

The whole code runs four times, an the result of `generator` is not returned to the for loop and not stored in the `sequence` array.

How can I modify the `sequence` function so it executes `someFunction` and `someOtherFunction` on different CPUs, and the return the XOR result of both of them to the `for loop` in the main file?
After I fill the `sequence` array, I'm going to pass it to the function `useTheSequenceArrayResultFromTheForLoopToCaclulateAndPrintTheFinalResult` to calculate the final result.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You run four instances of your program in parallel, but you forgot to collect all the results in one place using `MPI_Reduce(...)`. You can see a small example below of how you can do this. But you have to decide where you need to collect the results. You can collect them anywhere, but it is wise to collect them outside the loop for performance reasons.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define RESULT_1 0x55
#define RESULT_2 0xAA
#define UNDEFINED 0xBB

int calc(int id) {
    if (id == 0) {
        return RESULT_1;
    }
    return RESULT_2;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int id, local, global = UNDEFINED;

    MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);

    local = calc(id);

    MPI_Reduce(&local, &global, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_BXOR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    printf("at the moment: local=%02x, global=%02x\n", local, global);

    if (!id) {
        printf("Result is: %02x\n", global);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE #1**

When you run `mpirun` with the argument `-np 4`, you get 4 instances of your program running in parallel. If your computer has 4 cores, each instance gets a different value for variable `id`.

You can do any manipulations with any variable or array. But you should remember that all instances have independent set of variables. One instance can not access variables of other instance.

You can call `MPI_Reduce()` to combine the values of variables or arrays from different instances into single variable or array. The first argument is the pointer to the source. The second one is the pointer to the destination.

Only instance with `id == 0` will get the result. So if yo plan to print or use the result you have to do it inside the instance with `id == 0`.

Here is the same example rewritten for arrays instead of variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define SIZE_OF_ARRAY 16

#define RESULT_1 0x55
#define RESULT_2 0xAA
#define UNDEFINED 0xBB

int calc(int id) {
    if (id == 0) {
        return RESULT_1;
    }
    return RESULT_2;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i, id;
    static int local[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];
    static int global[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];

    MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++) {
        local[i] = calc(id);   
        global[i] = UNDEFINED; // just to show that this value will be altered
    }

    // for an instance with (id == 0), local elements will have a value of 0x55
    // for an instance with (id != 0), local elements will have a value of 0xAA
    // the value of elements of global is undefined here

    MPI_Reduce(local, global, SIZE_OF_ARRAY, MPI_INT, MPI_BXOR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // after this call the values of elements of global are undefined if (id != 0)
    // if (id == 0) the values of elements of global will be combination of
    // appropriate elements of local arrays from different instances
    // let's denote "var_0" the variable "var" from the instance #0
    // we will get:
    // global_0[i] = local_0[i] ^ local_1[i] ^ local_2[i] ^ local_3[i]

    if (!id) {
        // use the sequence array result from the loop here
        printf("Result is: [%02x", global[0]);
        for(i = 1; i < SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++) {
            printf(", %02x", global[i]);
        }
        printf(" ]\n");
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You didn't explain how can the OP store the results of `calc` in an Array to use them later in his function `useTheSequenceArrayResultFromTheForLoopToCaclulateAndPrintTheFinalResult `.

Comment: @Yazan There is no reason to retype all the documentation. I added a description of the main approach and an example with arrays. This site is a cookbook. Not a restaurant.